# Spreadsheet not saving to Rails database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, import-from-excel, roo-gem

I've managed to get a spreadsheet parsed through my Rails 5 app using the Roo gem, but once it finishes the process it doesn't seem to save to the database.

Here is my code:

```
require 'roo'

xlsx = Roo::Excelx.new(File.expand_path('../Downloads/LOCATION.xlsx'))

xlsx.each_row_streaming(offset: 1) do |row|

Location.find_or_create_by(ukprn: row[0]&.value, accomurl: row[1]&.value, instbeds: row[3]&.value, instlower: row[4]&.value, instupper: row[5]&.value, locid: row[6]&.value, name: row[7]&.value, lat: row[9]&.value, long: row[10]&.value, locukprn: row[11]&.value, loccountry: row[12]&.value, privatelower: row[13]&.value, privateupper: row[14]&.value, suurl: row[15]&.value)

end
```

This goes through each row with the correct attributes giving the following results:

```
Location Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."ukprn" = $1 AND "locations"."accomurl" = $2 AND "locations"."instbeds" = $3 AND "locations"."instlower" = $4 AND "locations"."instupper" = $5 AND "locations"."locid" = $6 AND "locations"."name" = $7 AND "locations"."lat" = $8 AND "locations"."long" = $9 AND "locations"."locukprn" = $10 AND "locations"."loccountry" = $11 AND "locations"."privatelower" = $12 AND "locations"."privateupper" = $13 AND "locations"."suurl" = $14 LIMIT $15  [["ukprn", "99999998"], ["accomurl", "http://www2.hull.ac.uk/student/accommodation-new/accommodationhull/first-year-students.aspx"], ["instbeds", 3033], ["instlower", 3500], ["instupper", "5200"], ["locid", "HC"], ["name", "The University of Hull"], ["lat", 53.76964], ["long", -0.367165], ["locukprn", 10007149], ["loccountry", "XF"], ["privatelower", 3100], ["privateupper", "3800"], ["suurl", "http://www.hullstudent.com/"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
```

and continues through all rows until the end row:

```
  Location Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."ukprn" = $1 AND "locations"."accomurl" = $2 AND "locations"."instbeds" = $3 AND "locations"."instlower" = $4 AND "locations"."instupper" = $5 AND "locations"."locid" = $6 AND "locations"."name" = $7 AND "locations"."lat" = $8 AND "locations"."long" = $9 AND "locations"."locukprn" = $10 AND "locations"."loccountry" = $11 AND "locations"."privatelower" = $12 AND "locations"."privateupper" = $13 AND "locations"."suurl" = $14 LIMIT $15  [["ukprn", "99999999"], ["accomurl", "http://www.bsms.ac.uk/undergraduate/our-course"], ["instbeds", 5720], ["instlower", 4785], ["instupper", "6011"], ["locid", "KF"], ["name", "Falmer"], ["lat", 50.860268], ["long", -0.085662], ["locukprn", 99999999], ["loccountry", "XF"], ["privatelower", 4977], ["privateupper", "5756"], ["suurl", "http://www.bsms.ac.uk/undergraduate/campus-life/student-life/"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.8ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
 => nil
```

For whatever reason however, this does not commit the data to the postgres database. I'm not sure why this is.

If I change the code to `Location.create!(ukprn: row[0]&.value, accomurl: row[1]&.value, instbeds: row[3]&.value, instlower: row[4]&.value, instupper: row[5]&.value, locid: row[6]&.value, name: row[7]&.value, lat: row[9]&.value, long: row[10]&.value, locukprn: row[11]&.value, loccountry: row[12]&.value, privatelower: row[13]&.value, privateupper: row[14]&.value, suurl: row[15]&.value)` it has the following error:

```
(485.6ms)  BEGIN
   (156.0ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Institute must exist
    from /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:78:in `raise_validation_error'
```

Where Institute is the reference (foreign key). Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `Validation failed: Institute must exist`

Comment: So the data needs an Institute id? Is there a way I can allocate it an id via the ukprn attribute in this table matching the ukprn attribute in the institute table?

Comment: Do you need the data to have this institute id, if not you can just disable the validation for it.

Comment: If you're using Rails 5, you can do `belongs_to :institution, optional: true`

Comment: Not necessarily, but it will need it at somepoint. The ukprn is a reference from one source, but there may be other data sources so wanted to ensure that the data remained flexible. Every row will be linked to an institute so it would be good to have it. Would something like `institute.find_by(ukprn, institute.ukrpn)` or something similar work?